# How to spell 'ewww' as in 'ewww ahhh'

Tags: expressions, orthography

I was wondering how I should spell 'ewww' as in 'ewww ahhh':

> Bob showed Jill his most impressive set of magic cards. Jill, impressed, said, 'ewwww[sp?] ahhhhhh.'

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-yCg-0-baE

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence? "Ewww ahhh" isn't enough to help me understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sure. Bob showed Jill his most impressive set of magic cards. Jill, impressed, said, 'ewwww[sp?] ahhhhhh.'

Comment: @MrHen maybe Ooh, aww! With ooh as in ooh-la-la?

Comment: or are you thinking of the ***"Hoo-ah"*** that the military uses to show agreement or approval?

Comment: Ewwww! Gross! Missspelllings. Hy-phens. (just to point out that there are several different possible meanings to the spelling "EWW.."; it's often a term of disgust. You have to ***hear*** it to tell which meaning is intended; normal English spelling is bad enough, but making up eye dialect impressionistic spellings for emotional intonations is even less likely to produce understanding.)

Comment: I've seen several non-native speakers spell this "oww" (with the usual varying number of trailing w's), which always make me think that they're in pain.

Comment: Amusingly, the video the OP just linked to in order to explain the sound has it spelled properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are trying to spell "ooo":

> Look at those fireworks! Ooo... ahh...

It can also be spelled with a trailing "h":

> Oooh... look at those purses!

"Ewww" is just an elongated form of "[ew](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ew#English)":

> 1. Expression of disgust or nausea. “Ew! There’s a fly in my soup.”

As for pronunciation, there is a subtle difference between the two. "Ooo" and "oooh" are pronounced like the vowel sound in "tool" or "fool". "Eww" sounds more like the vowel sound in "cute" with has an "ee+oo" diphthong.

Comment: So 'ooo' would sound like 'eww' when pronounced?

Comment: I added a note about pronunciation to the answer. Short version is that "ooo" wouldn't have the "eee" sound at the beginning that "ewww" does.

Comment: So to be clear: "eeeewww" is pronounced eeee-oooooow.  It further gets the point across if you make a face of disgust while saying it. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Correct. :)

Comment: 'Oooh... ahh...' Not to be confused with 'oo-aarh, me hearties'.